# MSB4018: The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly - Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My problem is that I removed my storage from the computer that had Visual Studio, I reinstalled Visual Studio, but for some reason it is still looking for the 'package folder' on the other storage, but of course it can't find it, so my question is how to change it the location of the 'package folder'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out this documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#config-section

Proceed as follows:

1.Find Nuget.config to modify the package storage path.

The default is C:\Users{UserName}\AppData\Roaming\NuGet

2.Add code

```
<config>
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="c:\packages" />
</config>
```

3.After the modification is completed, you need to restart visual studio.

The final effect:

[image]